# Database Layout for multiple time horizons

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-design, primary-key

I am currently working on a project to create a data base which contains multiple tables with different time horizons.
We use different hard and software on each testbench.
The goal is to document as much information as possible due to SPICE.

The hardware is changed every 5-6 month. 
The software on the other hand gets updates every 2-3 month.
The test cases change in a weekly period and even small changes in the test layout should be documentet if possible.

Im an just at the beginning for my SQL and data base journey.
My approach would be to split the data base into 3 to 4 tables with different updating periods.

**The Problem:**
I need to gernerate a complex key structure to make this possible.
It's hard to describe my approach to my collegues.

**The question:**
Is my approach to complex?
Am I on the wrong track?
Is there an easier way to save storage while also achieving the goal of complete documentation?

Comment: Generally you split data based on *relations*, so for example `Hardware` `Software` `Test` `TestResult` `TestHardware` `TestSoftware` (these last two are many-to-many linking tables). Do not fall into the trap of splitting your data horizontally, ie based on date, ID, test type etc, those should be in separate rows in the same table. Look up tutorials on *data normalization*

Comment: This Wikipedia article is a good start.  [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)